# Indicate that a protocol responds to any selector

Tags: objective-c, protocols, selector

On a complex library with lots of delegates and method forwarding. I get a lot of warnings on the main class saying it might not respond to the selector.

The object creator returns:

```
- (id<MainProtocol>) foo;
```

Is there a way to indicate to the Obj-C compiler that the protocol responds to any selector, without warnings ?

Thanks, JD

Comment: You get warnings that your object does not respond to MainProtocol methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to indicate to the Obj-C compiler that the protocol responds to any selector, without warnings ?

Protocols don't respond to selectors.  Objects respond to selectors.  The main purpose of a protocol is to produce those compile time warnings that you want to suppress.  So you will not be surprised when I say what you ask for can't be done.

You can suppress the warnings by casting the object to a plain `id`.